# google sheets if and statements not workings

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, match, nested-if

=IF(and('Form Responses 5'!BA:BA="Service/install",if('Form Responses 5'!Y:Y="V723")),sum('Form Responses 5'!Z:Z),"")

I want it so
if ba:ba="service.install" then add z:z
if ba:ba="sending" then add z:z

bonus if I could get it to be also included
if ba:ba="receive" then subtract z:z

if none of the above, do nothing

I keep getting 'wrong number of arguments'

I've been trying for about 3 hours. I can't get it do do much. Sometimes it'll say false in the cell.

edit:

I just noticed I missed putting in half of what I wanted. I want it so if ba:ba="service.install" and y:y="V723" then add z:z
if ba:ba="sending" and Y:Y="V723" then add z:z

bonus if I could get it to be also included if ba:ba="receive" then subtract z:z

if none of the above, do nothing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aeckdhKBFTlaRS42wzDM1lG0CTx_ultMqjjHkRkdzYk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Then I just noticed I missed putting in half of what I wanted.

I want it so if ba:ba="service.install" and y:y="V723" then add z:z if ba:ba="sending" and Y:Y="V723" then add z:z

bonus if I could get it to be also included if ba:ba="receive" then subtract z:z

if none of the above, do nothing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Sheet9 Cells c:c is where I want the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER('Form Responses 5'!Z:Z; REGEXMATCH(
                    'Form Responses 5'!BA:BA; "(?i)Service/install|sending");
                    'Form Responses 5'!Y:Y="V723")))
```

Comment: That is almost perfect I think, just need it to do the nothing if that isn't matched. So I don't get the #NA error

Comment: @MichaelYanos you can just wrap it into IFERROR

Comment: Just to be clear...This won't do the subtraction though right?

Comment: @MichaelYanos no, IFERROR will only hide errors